# Running each ssh command in one session

Tags: ssh

Commands the server through ssh.
The output of each command must be stored separately.

```
ssh -i ~/c.pem ubuntu@server 'cd /tmp'
ssh -i ~/c.pem ubuntu@server 'pwd'
```

I want to have "/tmp" output when I run this code.
How do I run multiple commands in previous session?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `;` between commands to execute them sequentially.

```
ssh -i ~/c.pem ubuntu@server 'cd /tmp; pwd'
```